# How combine push data (real time) and ordinary incremental updates in azure analysis services

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, ssas-tabular

I am just starting to figure out the best way to keep the data in our Power BI reports up to date as soon things happening. Our business case is that we have a web application that register input data from users. This is stored on a Azure Cosmos DB, but also send data to a Azure SQL Db which is my data source. When this is registered, it will be stored in the source Azure SQL DB. The Power BI reports have live connection to a Azure Analysis Services data model and get data from a star schema data warehouse (kimball way) azure SQL DB. The data warehouse and ssas data model is now updated on time like every 15 minutes. But there must be a better way to do this (I hope)

So perhaps we could use different approaches to get more real time updates. What we want to use is a pure Azure solution using Azure data factory to orchestrate the solution, but how. Basically the data model in SSAS should be basis for our analytical reports, but how can be easily add data from last data model process until the latest registration before the report runs?

1) if we go for a traditional solution with a data warehouse and ssas data model, we could end up with starting a new integration job every time something is registered, or
2) can we make use of Push Data REST Api to add data to the report? this approach is interesting but can be complicated to manange, as we need an additional data set which must cooperate with the data model somehow (like number of items: num items = numitems_history + numtimes_frompush), and when the data model is updated then the push dataset must be empty

We can imagine that the updated data mostly is fact data. Perhaps there are other smarter ways to do this and I am looking forward to hear suggestions from you or may be you have done implementations already.

Perhaps the easiest way is to make a day partition that manage the new data arriving today just for new fact data.

But again I am looking forward to hear from you all

Regards Geir F

Comment: I suppose one question that occurs to me is, if you really want real-time, why not have one Power BI report (possibly a separate one to your main analytical reports) which uses DirectQuery to the Azure SQL DB?  The real-time and Azure Analysis Services (AAS) could be complementary, eg serve different purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That has occurred to me also. Perhaps I am making a problem out of something that can be solved by thinking more easily